# Как можно зашифровать html код?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно зашифровать `html` код, через `JS` скрипт, и есть какие то `generator` ?

Comment: А какой смысл? Всё равно для показа его придётся расшифровать.

Comment: Никак и нет смысла

Comment: @D-side, более того, для расшифровки в принципе ничего не надо, так как ей займется сам браузер

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. можно значительно усложнить разбор HTML-а для другого разработчика
2. можно использовать javascript для псевдо шифрования

пример раз https://www.smartgb.com/free_encrypthtml.php

пример два http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561359-html-encrypter.aspx

в результате вместо читабельного html-а

```
<html></html>
```

получим

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HTML Encryption provided by www.webtoolhub.com -->
<!--
document.write(unescape('%3c%68%74%6d%6c%3e%3c%2f%68%74%6d%6c%3e'));
//-->
</script>
```

ещё раз -- это всё псевдо шифрование. новичков оттолкнёт, профессионала вообще никак не остановит.

Comment: ...и к тому же увеличит объём страниц примерно втрое.

Comment: @D-side, почему втрое?

Comment: @Grundy потому что выбран такой метод "шифрования", который на каждый символ исходного документа выдаёт по три "зашифрованного".

Comment: @D-side мы живёт в 21 веке, размер уже не так актуален

Comment: @Zam скажите это пользователям, которые зайдут на сайт устройством за 80 долларов с 2G-интернета.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko 1) пользователи 2G интернета очевидно не смогут принести нам никаких денег - не наш клиент. они нам не интересны. ты ещё вспомни пользователей с модемом на 2400 бот и без коррекции ошибок. А совместимость с IE4 и NN5 нынче в этом году не требуется? 2) в 2011 году мобильный телефон с 3G стоил уже $50. 3) уже планируется внедрение 5G в следующем году.

Answer (score 6):

### Нет смысла.

Браузеру нужен нормальный незашифрованный HTML, чтобы отобразить его пользователю.

Поэтому в какой-то момент в браузере будет собран нормальный отображаемый HTML, вполне поддающийся сохранению банальным <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> или инспектором.

Comment: вопрос был `Как можно зашифровать html код?`. ответ `Нет смысла.` не даёт ответа на вопрос

Comment: @Zam ещё как даёт. Ответ "эффективно -- никак".

Comment: эффективность - это уже другой вопрос. как можно это сделать - был дан чёткий ответ ниже.

Comment: @Zam нет, это тот же вопрос. Я предлагаю отказаться от решения этой проблемы вовсе, потому что любое возможное решение будет неэффективным для практически любых нужд. Ваше в том числе. Использовать экранирование в качестве шифрования это даже не смешно.